# How to make an element fit the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

So I'm making a game and I want the canvas to be the full width and height of the page.  I wrote up a function to get the width & height of the page:

```
function getWindowSize()
{
    var width = window.innerWidth
                || document.documentElement.clientWidth 
                || document.body.clientWidth;

    var height = window.innerHeight 
                 || document.documentElement.clientHeight 
                 || document.body.clientHeight;

    return {width:width, height:height};
}
```

And that's working pretty fine for getting the size of the page.  The trouble comes when I'm initiating my `Kinetic.Stage` object, and I have to set the width & height.  When I set the width and height of the stage to the width or height properties that are returned by `getWindowSize`, I get scrollbars, which is very annoying, and I have to subtract 25 from each value.


So what I'm asking is:  Is there any easy way to make an element fit the page for sure without using subtraction of my function's return value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you set your html/body to have no padding/margins?

Comment: Nope, just added a for loop to loop through each canvas and div element and change its padding, border, and margin to 0, and still nothing.

Comment: Ay caramba, no screenshot service I can think of will take a screenshot of canvas!

Comment: I can make a ZIP that you can open - I can't get it to work in JSFiddle.  I will attach a dropbox link shortly.

Comment: Sorry didnt see the mention of scrollbars appearing, as with johnny's answer you can set the html style to `overflow:hidden;` to make it so the scrollbars do not show up. Removed other comments to clean up the comment area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the canvas to be the entire width and height of the screen, then presumably you'd never want scrollbars, so couldn't you just do:

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

to prevent the scrollbars from being shown (and in some cases the page from scrolling at all)?

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around is make the vertical scrollbar always present, which is how I deal with this kind of problem:

```
html { 
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

Comment: Well, the point of my question is how to get the scrollbars to NOT show up.

Comment: @Atutouato `overflow:hidden;`